# Proper Fail2Ban Config Editing

Tags: fail2ban

There is some confusion left by various articles on the web about how to edit the Fail2Ban config files. For instance I wish to whitelist an IP address.

Some say to copy the jail.conf to jail.local and then to edit jail.conf. Some say to edit jail.local. Some say never to edit jail.conf because it will get overwritten by updates and such.

Worse, their own web site states:

```
Whitelisting is setup in the jail.conf file using a space separated list.
```

It also indicates to use the [Default] section and the ignoreip line when neither exists.

I think we can understand why users might get confused.

Does anyone know the best practice and why?

Thank you.